# How do I get a file's icon in Java?

Tags: java, icons, file-browser

I'm making a basic file browser and wish to display the icon of each file. Is there any way to get this?

Comment: is this for all operating systems or just windows?

Comment: @pstanton All operating systems. [I know this is late, but I wanted it here in case someone else came by and had the same question]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon( File );
```

Comment: This doesn't work well on OS X, it only returns a folder for directories or a generic file icon for any non-directories.

Comment: @SamBarnum is that still the case with Java 8 on OS X Yosemite?

Comment: Workaround for os x:  `final javax.swing.JFileChooser fc = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
      Icon icon = fc.getUI().getFileView(fc).getIcon(file);`