# Fetch icons of my System

Tags: javafx-2

I have made a program which shows my C and D drive.  But the icons which are coming in my output are the default icons of javaFx.  I just want to show all icons of my system.  For example for videos it should show the media icon for my system, not the default icon in javaFx.

Comment: Please add your code (and screenshot) because I am not really sure what actualy the question is.

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to:

- [How do I get a file's icon in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363251/how-do-i-get-a-files-icon-in-java)

That related question does not provide a native JavaFX solution.

However, there is currently no native JavaFX solution, so it would be best to:

1. Use the Swing classes referenced in the similar question.
2. Extract a BufferedImage from the icons, using:

   - [How to convert Icon from JLabel into BufferedImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368160/how-to-convert-icon-from-jlabel-into-bufferedimage)
3. Use [SwingFXUtils.toFXImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#toFXImage-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) to convert the BufferedImage to a JavaFX Image.

The related question suggests (and I haven't tried it) to do:

```
Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(File);
```

Or (if OS X):

```
javax.swing.JFileChooser fc = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
Icon icon = fc.getUI().getFileView(fc).getIcon(file);
```

After writing this answer, I found the following question which is similar (perhaps this is even a duplicate):

- [JavaFX file listview with icon and file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034432/javafx-file-listview-with-icon-and-file-name)